# Problems using next() and prev() methods for cyclic gallery - javascript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript and jQuery. I'm trying to create an online gallery to see photos, using 2 buttons "next" and "prev". It must be cyclic so, for example, if I click "next" when the last photo is displayed, the next photo must be the first one.

I tried to use 3 variables: first img, last img and current img, so that I just need to do currimg = currimg.prev() (or next). And, for example, if the img displayed is the first one, I do currimg = lastimg.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").wrapAll("<div></div>");
    $("img").nextAll().hide();
    var firstimg = $("img:first");
    var lastimg = $("img:last");
    var currimg = firstimg;

    $("#nextbutton").click(function(){
        currimg.fadeOut("fast", function(){
            (currimg==lastimg) ? currimg=firstimg : currimg=currimg.next();
            currimg.fadeIn("fast");  
        });  
    });

    $("#prevbutton").click(function(){
        currimg.fadeOut("fast", function(){
            (currimg==firstimg) ? currimg=lastimg : currimg = currimg.prev();
            currimg.fadeIn("fast");  
        });  
    });
});
```

The problem is that the cycle works only if I press firstly prev. If I click next and then twice prev, it doesn't work and it shows nothing. Where is the problem?

Comment: If you mean that I should only replace var currimg = firstimg with var currimg = lastimg (and replacing nextAll with prevAll), it doesn't change that much. That's not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your solution is that every time you assign to your *currimg* the values returned from `currimg=currimg.next();` or `currimg.prev();` you are assigning a new jQuery object.

This causes that when you make the comparison `(currimg==firstimg)` this will not be true even if both *currimg* and *firstimg* are pointing to the same DOM element.

In order to check if two jQuery objects point to the same DOM element you can use the [is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method.

So, your code should look something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $imgs = $("img");
    $imgs.wrapAll("<div></div>");
    $imgs.nextAll().hide();
    var firstimg = $imgs.first();
    var lastimg = $imgs.last();
    var currimg = firstimg;

    $("#nextbutton").click(function(){
        currimg.fadeOut("fast", function() {
            currimg = (currimg.is(lastimg)) ? firstimg : currimg.next();
            currimg.fadeIn("fast");  
        });  
    });

    $("#prevbutton").click(function(){
        currimg.fadeOut("fast", function(){
            currimg = (currimg.is(firstimg)) ? lastimg : currimg.prev();
            currimg.fadeIn("fast");  
        });  
    });
});
```

Note that I have also stored all your images in *$imgs* so that there is no need to do multiple selections of the images on your script startup. The use of the ternary operator has also been changed in order to be clearer/cleaner.

Comment: Thank you, you resolved my problem! I didn't know that, even if both currimg and firstimg are pointing to the same DOM element, the comparison (currimg==firstimg) would be always false.

Comment: Yeah! That is because when you compare two objects in JavaScript you are checking if they refer to the same object in memory (i.e. their references are the same), not if their values are the same (you can read more about this in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality).